# how to display the count of the images using java script or jquery in the count box, count display need to be in progressiveness counting

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<head>
  <style>
    #box {
      width: 300px;
      height: 60px;
      background: green;
      color: black;
      font-size: 20px; 
    }
    .images {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>    
  <div id="box">
    <p style="padding: 20px;">Images Count:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="images">        
    <img src="img001.jpg">
    <img src="img002.jpg">
    <img src="img003.jpg">
    <img src="img004.jpg">
    <img src="img005.jpg">
    <img src="img006.jpg">
  </div>
```

Please help me with the code to display the count, count display needs to be in progressiveness counting.

Comment: *count display need to be in progressiveness counting* What does this mean?

Comment: + gurvinder372, i mean to say the images count need to starts from 0 to the total count of the images in page

Comment: Is the image being added dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Images count="+ $(".images").find("img").length)

$("#imgcount").text( $(".images").find("img").length)
});
```

```html
<div id="box">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>

<p style="padding: 20px;">Images Count:</p>
</div>
<div class="images">        
<img src="img001.jpg">
<img src="img002.jpg">
<img src="img003.jpg">
<img src="img004.jpg">
<img src="img005.jpg">
<img src="img006.jpg">

</div>

Total No. of Images in page are <label id="imgcount">
```